# Removing adwaita-icon-theme with `apt remove` removed my entire desktop

Tags: apt, package-management, themes, 18.04

Upon installing Ubuntu 18.04, I noticed some applications were missing from the previous version as well as icons from the Adwaita icon theme. To attempt to fix these problems, I decided to begin by installing and reinstalling the Adwaita icon theme. This was done using the following command:

```
sudo apt remove adwaita-icon-theme
```

However, this started a chain reaction where every application on my machine started to delete itself until I had nothing left except a black terminal.

How can I fix this?

Comment: For future reference, APT has a `--reinstall` option that replaces all the files of a package without calculating dependency resolution for removal of the package (because it doesn't get removed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so I was playing around and found a solution.

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt install adwaita-icon-theme
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

That restored the apps that come with Ubuntu. I still have to install third party apps again..

I'll keep this for reference in case someone else makes the same mistake. I guess Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has bugs.